# Parallel port (LPT) file transfer software

Tags: windows, terminal, file-transfer, parallel-port

I am looking for (preferably freeware/opensource) Windows (XP/Vista) based application which allows files to be transferred across two computers through their parallel ports, something like Hyperterminal, except for parallel ports.

Comment: Which version of windows? There is native support in the DOS based windows through interlink or direct connect but I assume you are trying to do this on a xp or later system...

Comment: Do you have a null modem cable? If so, you can create an incoming connection in Network Connections on the LPT port, then create a connection TO the computer on the second one